# Publishing prerelease NuGet packages with dotnet CLI in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I have been playing with a pipeline but still haven't found a way to make *dotnet pack* in Azure DevOps create version "2021.10.22-**alpha**.1" (template is YYYY.MM.DD-alpha.Rev) for my library. I wasn't able to find a way to specify "alpha" at anywhere (yes, I tried everything).

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found it.

1. Set "Automatic package versioning" to `off` so no Version is passed
   to MSBuild. Otherwise it'd ignore any suffixes or prefixes
2. In
   "Additional build properties" set
   `VersionSuffix=foo;VersionPrefix=$(Build.BuildNumber)`
3. Adjust
   BuldNumber format in the Options section of the pipeline if need

Now my package version is "2021.10.22.8-foo". It's still not ideal but I'm on the right way.